# How can I clear an html form in angular.js?

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I have an add product form. When user submits it, I want to present him new add product form with reset values. How can I achieve this is angularjs?

Comment: This feels like an oDesk task description, not an actual question. What have you tried? Where are you getting an error?

Comment: This is such a basic, simple question, it doesn't deserve to be on stackoverflow, shows little or no research on the part of the OP.

Comment: do you want to add same form to page or reset previous form?

Answer (score 4):

Something like this.

HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
  <input type="text" ng-model="product.name">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.product = {
  name: 'My product'
};

$scope.submit = function() {
  // process the product data

  // Reset the product on the scope
  // which clears the form
  $scope.product = {};
}
```